# aiogram 3.4 как передать переменные из главного main.py в модули с роутерами

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram, бот

это мой первый вопрос, только что зарегался
Нужна помощь с телеграмм ботом aiogram 3.4 
В корне проекта есть файл main.py  где в самом начале создаю переменную settings в которую загружаю настройки из configs.yaml, а также tmp = {}.
В папке handlers есть модули bot_files.py и bot_messages.py внутри них @router
как из этих модулей иметь доступ к settings и tmp_owners?

вот main.py

```
import yaml
import asyncio
import os
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from handlers import bot_files, bot_messages

load_dotenv()
with open('config.yaml', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    settings = yaml.safe_load(f)
tmp_owners = {}


async def main():
    bot = Bot(token=os.getenv('TOKEN'))
    dp = Dispatcher()
    dp.include_routers(
        bot_messages.router,
        bot_files.router,
    )

    await dp.start_polling(bot)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

вот bot_files.py

```
from aiogram import F, Router, Bot
from aiogram.enums import ParseMode
from aiogram.types import Message

from functions import functions

router = Router()


@router.message(F.audio)
async def get_audio(message: Message, bot: Bot):
    await functions.print_message(message, settings, tmp_owners, bot)
    audio = message.audio
    await functions.get_audio_video_voice(message, audio, bot, 'audios')
```

а также и папки как они есть

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Чувствую себя как будто не знаю основ питона. я еше прохожу курсы и одновременно для личного пользования делаю телеграм бота. Оно какбы  работает хорjшо, но, там много костылей и структура уже бардак. Вот решил переписать и сразу ошибка. Раньше все хендлеры были внутри main.py

Comment: Это скорее будет попрашайничество) можете кто нибудь нажать + вопросу, пж )) узнал что есть "знаки" хочу заработать "Студент"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема решилась банальным импортом переменных внутри модулей bot_messages.py bot_files.py

```
from main import settings, tmp_owners
```

Comment: как закрыть вопрос?

Comment: Вопрос не нужно закрывать. Их закрывают тогда, когда они не соответствуют нормам сайта. Если вы хотите пометить, что вопрос "решен", пометьте свой ответ галочкой.